# Excel 2016: Query from folder not combining csv's by header row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I'm trying to combine multiple csv's in Excel 2016 using the New Query->From File->From Folder. I have done this in the past without any issues so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong this time.

Previously I could have sworn the option was called "Get Data" and before loading the query editor it opened a window where you could "Combine and Edit" the different csv's. That option seems to be gone, when I click "Ok" after selecting the folder I want it just loads straight into the query editor.

Now when I am in the query editor, I select Combine binaries, and then Transform->Use First Row as Headers. Then I Select Close&Load. It only promotes as headers the first row for the first file, previously I was able to edit and make it so all csv files were combined based on the headers in their first row. When the table loads, the columns are mismatched, as if I had just copied and pasted each csv together (see attached image).

[image: mismatched columns]

How do I get the query to combine the columns based on their column headers? Did Excel 2016 have an update or something that removed the Combine & Edit csv option? I tried a bunch of different options in the query editor and nothing seemed to work. I'm hesitant to try using the advanced editor because the whole point of this was to save me time and I'm worried that could take more time than I have, but I'm open to trying that if it's the only way.

EDIT: I tried it on another computer and was able to get it to work. I think that computer was Excel 365 whereas my work computer is Excel 2016. So I would re-frame my question as: does anyone know how (or if it's possible) to use "New Query->From File->From Folder" to join csv's by column headers, the same way you would in Excel 365 using "Get Data"?

Answer (score 0):

Combine should work fine for that scenario, without any further steps.

If your first file is a tidy representation of the rest, then PQ will generate the Promote Headers step inside the generated query: Transform Sample File ...

The Power Query UI is evolving so your exact experience may depend on your exact Excel version or PQ Add-In version.